# How to submit a brokeredmessage using the REST API

Tags: azure, servicebus

According to MSDN a Brokered Message can be submitted via the REST API and this brokered message can have the Properties key value pair as part of the message.  I have been able to submit a Brokered message but when I recieve it the Properties field on the message is not populated.  I must be encoding the Properties JSON incorrectly.

Here is the code snippet

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = _token;
        webClient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8";
        Guid messageId = Guid.NewGuid();
        webClient.Headers["BrokerProperties"] = @"{""MessageId"": ""{" + messageId.ToString("N") + @"}"", ""TimeToLive"" : 900, ""Properties"": [{""Key"" : ""ProjectId"", ""Value"" : """ + message.ProjectId + @"""}]}";

        // Serialize the message
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(RespondentCommitMessage));
        ser.WriteObject(ms, message);
        byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();

        byte[] response = webClient.UploadData(fullAddress, "POST", array);
        string responseStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

Does anyone have an example of submitting a BrokeredMessage using the BrokerProperties HTTP Header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the servicebus team has put up some silverlight and windows phone service bus samples on codeplex at http://servicebus.codeplex.com/. I quickly looked at the code for the silverlight chat sample and it appears to have all I need to publish brokered messages via the RESTFull API.

Answer (score 3):

Having had to do a bit of investigation / work with the REST API for the Azure Service Bus myself, I'll save you guys the trouble of digging through the silverlight chat example listed in the accepted answer and give you the actual lowdown.

There's just two things you need to know:

### 1) The BrokerProperties HTTP Request Header is not equivalent to the BrokeredMessage.Properties collection

The Properties dictionary on a BrokeredMessage object is a collection of custom properties, whilst the BrokerProperties HTTP Request Header is where you specify the inbuilt properties normally associated with a BrokeredMessage, such as the Label, TimeToLive, etc.

### 2) All custom HTTP Request Headers are treated as custom properties

From MSDN: *In addition to these properties (referring to BrokerProperties), you can specify custom properties. If a single message is sent or received, each custom property is placed in its own HTTP header. If a batch of messages is sent, custom properties are part of the JSON-encoded HTTP body.*

So that means all you have to do to add your custom properties is to add the header, for example:

```
    public static void SendMessageHTTP(string bodyContent, params KeyValuePair<string,object>[] properties)
    {
        //BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(bodyContent);            
        //foreach(var prop in properties)
        //{
        //    message.Properties[prop.Key] = prop.Value;
        //}

        ...

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = token;
        webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8";

        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            webClient.Headers[prop.Key] = prop.Value.ToString();
        }
        webClient.Headers["MyCustomProperty"] = "Value";

        webClient.UploadData(messageQueueURL, "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyContent));            
    }
```

Very worthwhile reads are the [MSDN reference on the Send Message API endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780786.aspx) and the [introduction to the REST API itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798895.aspx) (this is where it talks about custom properties). There's also [an article with sample code here on the Azure Website documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-brokered-tutorial-rest/).